# Gradle - compileJava - remove compile Warnings

Tags: java, gradle, warnings, compiler-warnings

We use Gradle 2.1 and java plugin. During compileJava different warnings occur, for example:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
Note: ../SomeClass.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

We know what they mean but won't fix them (don't ask, other thread :)  Is there a way to avoid these messages somehow? They disturb the output a lot:

```
:project1:compileJava
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
Note: SomeClass.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 warning
:project1:processResources
:project1:classes
:project1:jar
:project2:compileJava
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning
:project2:processResources
:project2:classes
:project2:jar
:project2:war
```

Isn't is possible for example to redirect the stderr stream during compileJava so that we can grep out the warnings?
Or is there another way?

Comment: I used 'compileJava.options.warnings = false' and 'compileTestJava.options.warnings = false' but this just solved some problems. To avoid to much waste of time I went to the other teams and solved the 'problem' on their code side.

Comment: Ugh, I hate the fact that Gradle makes you edit the build files. This has to be the biggest reason I would stick to Maven if it was my choice.

Answer (score 12):

try this:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.warnings = false
}
```

Comment: this removes for me that warnings about bootstrap, but not the notes about deprecation. I'm not sure if it was clear that I also want to avoid them, nevertheless +1

Comment: Doesen't get rid of `sun.*` deprecation warnings for men.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding:

```
options.compilerArgs += '-Xlint:-deprecation'
```

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'options'

Comment: @Xerus i think cmginty means to put that line in a JavaCompile task configuration block, ie.

`tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += '-Xlint:-deprecation'
}`

Answer (score 2):

No answer posted so far that currently works (Gradle 4.0.1), so here's what does work:

```
options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
```

Comment: I hate how gradle doesn't allow such options at invocation time. This is why I prefer maven.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat You could easily define a specific property, and set that on the command line to do suppress exactly that what you want to be suppressed.

Answer (score 2):

`--warning-mode none` can be used to avoid printing warnings if you are running gradle build from terminal.

```
./gradlew clean build --warning-mode none
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on the warnings. For the warnings I was getting, this worked:

```
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs += ["-nowarn", "-XDenableSunApiLintControl"]
    }
```

Sanity restored.