# Add compiler settings for gradle task via commandline

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to add a compiler settings to `.gradlew clean test`? I don't want to modify gradle.build as I want to have cleaner console output and not see all compilation warnings / deprecations.

I found here: [Gradle - compileJava - remove compile Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572602/gradle-compilejava-remove-compile-warnings) that I could add:

```
options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
```

in build.gradle but is tthere an option to pass that in command line directly?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : no you can't do that.

You can only pass [project properties or Java system properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11696629/2003986)

You will have to change your `build.gradle` in order to add this manually or dynamically, using the project properties build-in system.