# Gradle and Maven act differently when send null as varargs parameter

Tags: maven, gradle, compiler-warnings, variadic-functions

I'm having unit test checking my function that receive varargs of String.

In the function i'm checking if the parameter sent is null:

```
public static String generate(String... input) {
        if (input == null) {
            LOGGER.warn("Input is null for CheckSumGenerator");
            return null;
        }
     // Other not relevant code here
}
```

Unit test:

```
String checkSum2 = CheckSumGenerator.generate(null);
Assert.assertEquals(checkSum2, null);
```

When using Maven as build tool - test run fine. Passed.
When change the project to run with gradle the build print warning in red:

> warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type
>   for last parameter

The question is why gradle print it and maven isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maven compiler plugin is configured to ignore warnings by default

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#showWarnings

> `<showWarnings>` Set to true to show compilation warnings.
>
> ```
> Type: boolean
> Since: 2.0
> Required: No
> User Property: maven.compiler.showWarnings
> **Default: false**
> ```

On the other hand, Gradle displays them by default. [You can turn them off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572602/gradle-compilejava-remove-compile-warnings).